# iOS file writing failure

Tags: ios, ios5

I've been trying to write a string into a file in iOS5.1, but the file content is always (null). Can you help me figure out the reason?
Here's my code:

```
NSString *dir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydirectory"];

NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 64];

for (int i=0; i<DEFAULT_LENGHT_OF_NOTE_FILE_ID; i++) 
{
    [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
 }

 NSString* randomFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.html",randomString];
 NSString *filePath = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:randomFileName];

 NSString *str = @"Mystr";

//save content to the documents directory
 [str writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
                       error:nil];


 NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                        usedEncoding:nil
                                                               error:nil];

 NSLog(@"%@", content);
```

The NSLog always returns (null). What am i doing wrong?

Sincerely,

Zoli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following

```
NSString *dir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mydirectory"];
```

to

```
NSString *dir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

Comment: @ZoltanVaradi thats good news :) please consider accepting the answer if it fixed your problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't have write access to that file. Try writing to your Documents folder instead.

```
//Get the documents folder
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

...

NSString *filePath = [dir stringByAppendingPathComponent:randomFileName];
[str writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
                       error:nil];
```

You could always use the error in writeToFile and print it to find out your error.

```
NSError *error = nil;
[str writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy 
                       error:&error];
if(error) NSLog(@"Error:%@" error.localizedDescription);
```